# Phpmyadmin not opening html table (potential server issue)

Tags: php, mysql, html-helper

I am having issues with linking mysql to html through a server, the ports are all in order and the I have had no issues in linking the server to phpmyadmin. I have no password on the server and the username is 'root'.

please help :)

```
          <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root"
        $password= "";
        $database = "stock_order";
        $connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database)
```

I believe this might be an error because my server port is 3008 however, that shouldn't be an issue

```
        // checking connection
        if ($connection)->connect_error {
          die("connection failed: " . $connection ->connect_error);
         }

        //read the data from the customer table
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM customertable";
        $result = $connection->query($sql);

        if (!$result) {
            die("Invalid query: " .$connection->error);
         }

         // while loop - reads data of each row
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr>
<td>" . $row["ItemID"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["ItemName"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["Quantity"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["Description"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["DeliveryMerchant"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["Cost_of_item"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["VAT_Percentage"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["VAT"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["Total_cost_of_item"] . "</td>
<td>
     <a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' href='update'>Update</a>
     <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' href='delete'>Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>";
          }
        ?>

    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>78956</td>
            <td>Merch 2008 Monitor 4K</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Fragile</td>
            <td>TPL Resources</td>
            <td>£1080</td>
            <td>20%</td>
            <td>£216</td>
            <td>£1296</td>
            <td>
                <a href='update'>Update</a>
                <a href='delete'>Delete</a>
            </td>
       </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>

      <body>

    </body>

     <?php
      $conn-mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "customer_order_table");
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM stock_order";
      $result = $conn ->query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["itemID"] . "<tr><td>" . $row["ItemName "] . "<tr><td>" . 
     $row["Quantity"] . 
     "<tr><td>" . $row["Description"] . "<tr><td>" . $row["DeliveryMerchant"] . "<tr> 
     <td>" . $row["VAT_Percentage"]
     . "<tr><td>" . $row["VAT"] . "<tr><td>" . $row["Total_cost_of_item"] . "<tr><td>"
     } 
     }
       else {
     echo "No Results";
       }
       $conn ->close();
       ?>
     </style>
    </table>
      </body>
      </html>
```

when I type in 'localhost/customertable/' in the address bar the page cannot be found, displaying an error 404.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `404` means, in general, that the requested `URL` doesn't exist on the server. In short, the `404` doesn't seem to be linked to how you connect to the the Database.

Comment: Do you have rewrite rules in place, or is `customertable` a directory and you defined the documentroot for it? (Unrelated security issue, `root` should not be used for an application and should have a password associated with it)